# BitMEX panda dataframe to nd array

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading

Hi can anyone covert the following code to an nd array. I have imported panda as pd. This is python.

```
def predict(self):
    ohlcv_candles = pd.DataFrame(self.client.Trade.Trade_getBucketed(
        binSize=self.timeframe,
        symbol='XBTUSD',
        count=100,
        reverse=True
    ).result()[0])
```

Comment: I want to use this with the talib which requires nd array

Comment: What have you tried yet ?

Comment: i haven't tried anything yet i am really new to this and not sure what to do

Comment: TypeError: Argument 'real' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got DataFrame)       This is the error i get when i try to run the program

Comment: I was able to convert by using np.array. but now i cant use timeperiod which was a part of pandas. do you know of any substitiues. I am trying to create a SMA crossover bot and i had timeperiod defined as the numbers of candles to use for the sma